# Android License Verification strange behaviour

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

I have a strange behaviour and I do not have any explanation for this. Can someone help me out ?

- I implemented LV into my app.
- I uploaded this app as a payable app into Google Play.
- I am testing the app now
- I sent the app by gmail to my testing google account. I like to simulate to have a cracked version.
- I installed the "cracked" version and I am happy to see, that my app denied the access.
- I uninstalled the "cracked" app.
- I purchased the same app from google play (I see a button with the price on it ) and let it install and I am happy to see the the app allows me to use it.

Everything good so far.

- I refunded my own order with the "Wallet Merchant Center" and I see in the status, that it was cancelled.
- I retry to install and run the "cracked" version.
  !!! My app allows me to use the app !!!
  !!! In GooglePlay I see that the install button has no price and I can still install the app, even the order was canceled !!!

I expected that in google play I see the button with the price again and that my "cracked" app denies me the access ?
This would mean, that if someone asks me to refund the order (after the official 30 minutes) and I do so, the user is still able use the app but for free !!!

Can someone explain me this ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably decided for the `ServerManagedPolicy`. It uses a license file to avoid asking the license server too much.

Now, the bought version of your app saves a valid license file in the file system. If for some reason (e.g. you changed the path of this license file) the file is not deleted when refunding, it is still valid.

That means, if you now install your "cracked" version and it finds this license file, it allows the app to run.

Usually, the initial values in the license file avoid running it much longer than the refund period. So, you will see that after some time of usage the license locks your cracked version, which solves your problem automatically, admittedly with an unexpectedly long delay.